# How to hide a Visible Object in MS Access?

Tags: vba, forms, ms-access

I have a button named **btnSave** that by default is not visible and when I clicked the button **btnAdd**, this is the time that **btnSave** showed. My aim is to make this button invisible again when I clicked it but I am getting this error:

```
Run-time error '2165':

You can't hide a control that has the focus.
```

This is how my code looks like:

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click()
   
   ....
   Me.Refresh
   Me.Repaint
   Me.btnSave.Visible = False
   Me.btnCancelSave.Visible = False

End Sub
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The error message is clear - object cannot be set invisible while it has focus. Move focus elsewhere.

```
Me.someothercontrol.SetFocus
Me.btnSave.Visible = False
Me.btnSaveCancel.Visible = False
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will take note of that.

Answer (score 0):

After several googling this is what I found and thanks to the Author (Mike Wolfe). Here is the link: [Fix for the error: "You can't hide a control that has the focus" in Microsoft Access](https://nolongerset.com/defocusifactive/)